# My Profile page, UPDATE details PHP MYSQL, verify uniqueness logic

Tags: php, mysql, post, sql-update, logic

I have a html form where fields username and e-mail should be unique on registration. I have succesfully made this registration page and it verifies uniqueness for username and email, it checks password strength, etc.

I then made a My Profile page, accessible only after logging in, where I should let users update their details, even email and username. I made this form be filled out by reading user data initially, like this

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $user_data['username']?>"/>
```

a.s.o

The rules used for registering should obviously be consistent in updating account details too. Therefore I used the same code for checking these fields. I ran into a problem though.

**Let's say we have username Billy and Billy2. Billy can't update to Billy2 because Billy2 already exists. Perfect. 
But Billy can't update to Billy because Billy exists already too.**

The commented if is my attempt at solving the problem and although that allowed me to leave Billy as Billy, it also discounts uniqueness, it let me update Billy to Billy2, not cool because there's now two Billy2.

So here's the full code for myprofile.php

How would you solve this?

```
    <?php 
include 'core/init.php';
protect_page();

if (empty($_POST) === false) {

    $required_fields = array('username', 'password', 'password_again', 'first_name', 'last_name' 'email');
            foreach($_POST AS $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required.';
            break 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors) === true) {

        if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
                $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long.';
            } elseif (($_POST['password']) !== ($_POST['password_again'])) {
                $errors[] = "Sorry, new password doesn't match. Please try again.";
            } 
            if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_again']) {
                $errors[] = 'Passwords don\'t match.';
            }

        // if ($user_data['username'] !== $_POST['username'] && $user_data['email'] !== $_POST['email']) {
            if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
                $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username \'' . $_POST['username'] . '\' is already taken.';
            }
            if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) === true) {
                $errors[] = 'Your username must not contain any spaces.';
            }

            if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                $errors[] = 'A valid email address must be provided.';
            }
            if (email_exists($_POST['email']) === true){
                $errors[] = 'Sorry, the email address \'' . $_POST['email'] . '\' is already in use.';
            }
        }
    // }
}

// print_r($errors);

include'includes/overall/header.php'; 
?>
    <h1>My Profile</h1>
    <br>
    <p>Here you can change your account details or <br><a href="index.php">Cancel and return</a> to the Homepage.</p>

    <?php 
    if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
        echo 'Your details have been succesfully updated.';
    } else {

                        if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
                            change_password($session_user_id, $_POST['password'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['email']);
                            Header('Location: changedetails.php?success');
                            } elseif (empty($errors) === false) {
                                echo output_errors($errors);
                            }
                        ?>

                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Username:*<br>
                                <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $user_data['username']?>"/>
                            </li><br>
                            <li>First Name:*<br>
                                <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $user_data['first_name']?>"/>
                            </li><br>
                            <li>Last Name:*<br>
                                <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $user_data['last_name']?>"/>
                            </li><br>
                            <li>Email:*<br>
                                <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $user_data['email']?>"/>
                            </li><br>

                            <br><h2>Change Password:</h2>

                            <li>
                                New Password*:<br>
                                <input type="password" name="password" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Confirm New Password*:<br>
                                <input type="password" name="password_again" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="submit" value="Update Profile">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="index.php">Cancel</a>
                    <?php 
            }
include'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each set of checks of `username` and `email` with a test whether it has changed, instead of wrapping all the checks in a single test of whether either has changed.

```
if ($user_data['username'] !== $_POST['username'] {
    if (user_exists($_POST['username']) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username \'' . $_POST['username'] . '\' is already taken.';
    }
    if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Your username must not contain any spaces.';
    }
}
if ($user_data['email'] != $_POST['email']) {
    if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'A valid email address must be provided.';
    }
    if (email_exists($_POST['email']) === true){
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, the email address \'' . $_POST['email'] . '\' is already in use.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh well, that did it. How did I not see it? Thanks Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

first of all: don't let user to modify key fields as username or password...you will have lots of problems if your database grows and other tables has relation with user table through key fields like username or email.
now lets face the problem.you should check the uniqueness of email AND username together,not each of them seperatly. so 'user_exists' function should get two parameters ,username and email and check if a row with given email AND passwords exists or not.

Comment: How I don't like it when people say X should be done X way because that's how they're used to do it. Not even related to best coding practices either. All in all, there will not be any problems because username and email are always called from the table with a user_id, which is incrementally unique. 

As for your second comment, it doesn't face the problem either. Again, I want user_exists() and email_exists() functions separate so I can output separate errors: "Email already in use." / "Username already in use."

Can anybody chime in, with practical answers please?

Comment: @J. Doe you should check the existance of username and email together...a unique key is combination of these two key together.

Comment: With no harm intended, I disagree.

Comment: @J. Doe Ok...that was my suggestion...i will be happy if you try it and give me a feed back,,,